How to open urls from Palantir Foundry dataset or Ontology object built over the dataset?
I have a foundry dataset which has 2 columns Title and URL and the rows are populated with the information i.e. titles and urls. Is it possible to open the website url from Foundry dataset or from Ontology object built over the dataset?
I am also ok with using button widget in the workshop application and passing url as an action, however the url buttons should be selectively visible to the users? In this case how do I apply the selective visibility settings?
I created the dataset and set datatype as string, however it didn't work out. And even in ontology object datatypes this option is not given.

One option where links are clickable is in object tables:

Here are the steps to set this up.

In Ontology Manager, setup a column of links as a string property and note the "ID" from property's Details tab (here it's "link_id"):


In a Workshop Object Table, add a URL column:


Configure the URL column using the property id from before:



